# The correct way to passing connection as parameter to different function in mysql2 nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mysql2, node-mysql2

it's my sample code

```
// database.js
exports.connection = mysql2.createPool({
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.DB_PASS,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME,
      supportBigNumbers: true,
      bigNumberStrings: true,
      dateStrings: true,
    });
```

```
// users.js
const { connection } = require('./database.js');

async function createUsers(params) {
  const conn = await connection.getConnection();
  try {
    await conn.beginTransaction();
    const sql = "INSERT INTO users (name,pass) VALUES (?,?)";
    const [id] = await conn.query(sql, [params.user, params.pass]);

    // i want to passing connection to any function like this
    await loginRoles(conn, { id: id.insertId, role: "user" });

    await conn.commit();
    return id.insertId;
  } catch (error) {
    await conn.rollback();
    return Promise.reject(error);
  } finally {
    conn.release();
  }
}
async function loginRoles(conn, params) {
  try {
    const sql = "INSERT INTO login (id, role) VALUES (?,?)";
    return conn.query(sql, [params.id, params.role]);
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
}
```

Is it the right way to passing connection as parameter to different function? I've tested this code, and it is works.. But is this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

`connection` is just an object that stores some methods to interact with a database, so it's ok to pass this object to some functions.
One thing you should remember: try to not modify this object in functions you invoke. It can lead to memory leaks.